# Formatting java.sql.Date string in JSP using JSTL formatDate

Tags: jsp, jstl, date-format

I'm having a problem with JSTL formatDate when displaying dates from MySQL database. I am using DAO layer for communication with database and in beans, dates are stored in `java.util.Date` objects. In JSP the code looks like this:

`<fmt:parseDate value="${season.startDate}" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy."/>`

When I try to run this page I get `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2009-09-01 00:00:00.0"`.I understand why this is unparseable but I don't know how to make it parseable. I am not sure if I can use `parseLocale` attribute because this date format is ANSI SQL date format and it is not represented by any `Locale` object.

How to fix this using JSTL?

Comment: YOu say you understand why this is unparseable. Is season.startDate a java.util.Date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to parse what already appears to be a date object ?  Is season.startDate a String ?  If it is a String, you need only change your parse format to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.z.  If it's not, then are you parsing the date instead of formatting it (...by accident) ?

Comment: Oh dear! It is by accident. Unfortunately, I lost half a day figuring it out. Thanks